# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation:

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

after submitting i get this error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '.'died','MALE','A','everyday','waiting','for','you')' at line 2 
>   ..

here is my code

```
extract($_POST);
if(isset($add)){
$sql = "INSERT INTO `tbl_patients` (`dateadd`,`pfname`,`plname`,`pdob`,`address`,`pgender`,`pbtype`,`pheight`,`pweight`,`fallergy`,`mallergy`)
    VALUES ('$date','$fname','$lname','$dob'.'$address','$gender','$bloodtype','$hgt','$wgt','$falrgs','$malrgs')";
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using dot(.) here `'$dob'.'$address',`  should be comma(,)
try to replace

```
'$dob'.'$address',
```

to

```
'$dob','$address',
```

so full query :-

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `tbl_patients` (`dateadd`,`pfname`,`plname`,`pdob`,`address`,`pgender`,`pbtype`,`pheight`,`pweight`,`fallergy`,`mallergy`) VALUES('$date','$fname','$lname','$dob','$address','$gender','$bloodtype','$hgt','$wgt','$falrgs','$malrgs')";
```

Comment: thank you so much never thought i used . instead of , . thanks a lot. very thankful

Answer (score 1):

`,` is missing.

```
'$dob','$address'
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be -

```
"INSERT INTO `tbl_patients` (`dateadd`,`pfname`,`plname`,`pdob`,`address`,`pgender`,`pbtype`,`pheight`,`pweight`,`fallergy`,`mallergy`)
VALUES ('$date','$fname','$lname','$dob','$address','$gender','$bloodtype','$hgt','$wgt','$falrgs','$malrgs')
```

There was a `.` instead of `,`